# PHP Mail with 2 attachments

Tags: php, email, attachment

I have the following code to send mails with an attachment, and I'm having trouble adapting it to send 2 attachments instead of just one. I need to send a .docx and a .pdf

Any idea on what should I modify?

```
    function mail_attachment($filename1, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {
        $file = $path.$filename;
        $file_size = filesize($file);
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);
        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
        $name = basename($file);
        $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
        $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/msword; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
        mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header);  
    }
```

And this is how I call it..

```
    mail_attachment("attachment.docx", "","recipient@mail.com","admin@mail.com","Admin","admin@mail.com","Subject","Mail body");
```

Comment: Don't build your own mime emails. Use PHPmailer or Swiftmailer. they can do all that with far less code/hassle.

Comment: ditto. is there any reason that you want to use a home grown solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use PHPMailer - a stable library which is easy to use and will do all your work! http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();

$mail->AddAddress("email@example.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test 1";
$mail->Body = "Test 1 of PHPMailer.";
```

You will be able to add attachments in one string:

```
$mail->AddAttachment('/home/mywebsite/public_html/file1.zip', 'file1.zip');
$mail->AddAttachment('/home/mywebsite/public_html/file2.zip', 'file2.zip');
```

It's easier and more flexible. Don't do th monkey's work. It's already done for you!
Programmers must be lazy! Type less code)

Comment: Here is some documentation http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html#Preparing_PHPMailer hope you will find it interesting.

Comment: @SpiderQ - old school is all well and good, but one of the main the reasons new school exists is because it's *easier*. You've got to admit that writing five lines of readable and reliable code is preferable to writing 30 lines of unreadable and easily broken code?